# Regexp beginner: how to remove comma before a keyword?

Tags: python, regex, perl

I have a string

"THIS IS, A STRING, FROM"

How can I remove a comma before the FROM statement?

Comment: Why is this tagged both [perl] and [python]?  Which are you looking for?

Comment: I was looking for an example, using perl or python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
,(?=\s*FROM\b)
```

Or, with many keywords:

```
,(?=\s*(?:FROM|TO|COUNT)\b)
```

In Python (case insensitive):

```
remove_commas = re.compile(r',(?=\s*FROM\b)', re.IGNORECASE)
str = remove_commas.sub('', str)
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/etEnt

Answer (score 2):

A Perl Example:

```
$text = "THIS IS, A STRING, FROM";
$text =~ s/,(\s*FROM)\b/$1/;
```

[http://codepad.org/](http://codepad.org/yh3hXm0m)

Answer (score 0):

Replace using regular expression `\,\s*FROM` and replace with `FROM`.